# iPhone : Cannot launch facebook dialog from alert view

Tags: iphone, ios4, facebook

The facebook dialog is not launching from alert view handler. 
But facebook dialog launches OK from button.

The code of launching facebook dialog is following

```
- (void) share_on_facebook
{
    _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];   
    NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
    NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"a long run", @"name",
                                @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                                @"it is fun", @"description",
                                @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];
    NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                   actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                   attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                   nil];
    [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

The handler of alert view is button click

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self share_on_facebook];
}
```

The facebook dialog is not launched but when I call share_on_facebook from ordinary button click handler the dialog opens successfully.

Please help to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(share_on_facebook)]; should do the trick

Comment: Still no success :( can you please provide some full code snippet ... ?